# RPMForge Package Centos 7 Mirror

Tags: rpm

I try to install RPMForge in Centos 7 from here [repoforge](http://repoforge.org/use/) , i cant access this url http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm , their server is down ,

Does anyone have any mirror for RPMForge in Centos 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's a working example link** I put together using a mirror. I think this is what you want.

http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm

**Full mirror list from** http://mirrorlist.repoforge.org/

---

```
http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://ftp.colocall.net/pub/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://ftp.fi.muni.cz/pub/linux/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://ftp.is.co.za/mirror/ftp.rpmforge.net/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://ftp.kddilabs.jp/Linux/RPMS/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://ftp.nluug.nl/os/Linux/distr/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://ftp.wa.co.za/pub/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://merlin.fit.vutbr.cz/mirrors/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mir01.syntis.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.awanti.com/rpmforge/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.crazynetwork.it/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.de.leaseweb.net/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.fairway.ne.jp/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.hmc.edu/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.lstn.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.nexcess.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.nl.leaseweb.net/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.smartmedia.net.id/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.team-cymru.org/rpmforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.teklinks.com/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.us.leaseweb.net/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.ventraip.net.au/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.veriteknik.net.tr/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.vit.com.tr/mirror/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.vutbr.cz/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror.zetup.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirror1.hs-esslingen.de/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/dag/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirrors.m247.ro/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirrors.neterra.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://mirrors.netix.net/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://repoforge.cu.be/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://repoforge.eecs.wsu.edu/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://repoforge.gtdinternet.com/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://repoforge.mirror.constant.com/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://repoforge.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://repoforge.spinellicreations.com/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
http://repoforge.xpg.com.br/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/repoforge/redhat/el7/en/$ARCH/rpmforge
```

Comment: If you can fix the formatting, be my guest... I give up.

Comment: with stuff like config files arguably the best formatting you can use is marking it as pre-formatted *"code"* . Paste, select again and then use the edit menu to mark it as pre-formatted usually works (that will pre-pend the four spaces to each line marking them as formatted code)  but the `<pre>  </pre>` HTML tags are also allowed.